# Is there a function or a way in Pine Script to get to total number of days (or percentage of days) you were in the market?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Seems like a simple problem but I can't figure it out.  e.g backtesting a strategy over the last year, I see I was in 5 trades for a total of 100 days.  How do I figure out the percentage of the total number of days I was in a trade?

I'm a newbie and can't find out how to do it

Answer (score 1):

The most simple approach would to utilise the value `strategy.position_size`

The main thing to do is to store a variable, that is kept over all script execution over all bar.

```
var daysInTrade = 0
```

This variable is declared and initialised on the first bar and in contrast to (all other) series values, it's value is kept over all bars. Then you can increment this value once on each bar, when you have a position

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
  daysInTrade += 1
```

For a first output use `plotchar` which logs the value of each bar within the data window, later you could display the result in a `table`.

```
plotchar(daysInTrade, char="", title="DaysInTrade")
```

This call will lead to a Warning in the console output. Just ignore it while debugging.

Comment: Thank you.  I see the warning on the plot but nothing is appearing on the chart. 
longCondition = ta.crossover(close, r1)
entryPrice = close
var daysInTrade = 0
qty = (strategy.equity * (.02) / math.abs(entryPrice - stopLoss))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,qty=qty)
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        daysInTrade += 1
        
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit,comment="SL/TP")
plotchar(daysInTrade, char="", title="DaysInTrade")

Comment: Yeah, an empty string is plotted. Check the buttons on the right side. There you find the data window, that shows you the data of each plot.